# How to prevent capture with Objective-C on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Capture must be prevented due to copyright. Through stackovetflow and search I have succeeded in getting a black blank screen to be captured.
Now, when capturing, I want the text to be centered on the white screen instead of the black blank screen.

```
@interface UIWindow (Secure)

- (void)makeSecure;

@end

@implementation UIWindow (Secure)

- (void)makeSecure {
    UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    field.secureTextEntry = YES;

    field.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    field.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    field.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    field.text = @"Prevent Capture";
    field.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    
    [self addSubview:field];
    [field.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerYAnchor].active = YES;
    [field.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.layer.superlayer addSublayer:field.layer];
    [field.layer.sublayers.firstObject addSublayer:self.layer];
}

@end

- (void)handleScreenshotNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
 
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                                             message:@"prevent Capture"
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *dismissAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:dismissAction];
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
...
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleScreenshotNotification:)
                                                     name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification
                                                   object:nil];
[self.window makeSecure];
...
}
```

I wrote the code as above but it still captures a black blank screen.

I want to add text to the center of the screenshot on a white background. Is there a way?